# TFS 2013: HTTP code 503: Service Unavailable

Tags: iis, tfs

All of a sudden, our TFS server down. When I checked in IIS, http://localhost:8080/tfs is giving 503 service error.

Below application pools are getting stopped automatically, even though I manually made them start in IIS manager.
Microsoft Team Foundation Server Application Pool, Microsoft Team Foundation Server Proxy Application Pool

Please guide me to solve this issue

Comment: Did you check the Event Viewer on TFS server?

Comment: @ds19: I found below Application event in Event Viewer. Exception Message: The http request operation timed out after 00:15:00. (type TimeoutException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildMachine.StartOperation.End(IAsyncResult result, HttpRouter& router, TfsMessageQueue& messageQueue, List`1& processHosts, MachineLifecycleActivity& traceActivity)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildMachine.EndStart(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Machine.WindowsService.EndStartMachine(IAsyncResult result)

Comment: Do you have any errors in Event Viewer: Applications and Services Logs-->Microsoft - Team Foundation Server-->Debug ?

Comment: In Applications and Services Logs-->Microsoft - Team Foundation Server-->Build services->Operational, I found this error. There is no Debug folder. "Build machine rdb-brs-devapp lost connectivity to message queue tfsmq://buildservicehost-1006/.
Reason: HTTP code 503: Service Unavailable"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This problem occurred due to network problem. Below steps solved the issue.

1. I changed the server from domain to workgroup and restarted the machine.
2. Again I changed from workgroup to domain and restarted the machine.
3. Goto IIS manager->Application Pools->Right click on Microsoft Team Foundation Server Application Pool->Advance Settings
4. Under Process Model section, Set the identity again with my domain credentials
5. reset IIS by running `IISReset` command as admin

Thank you for your replies.

Comment: Thanks. But maybe steps 3 and 4 are enough, isn't it?

Comment: Yes - I was able to just set a the same identity again and the Application Pool started.

Comment: #3 & #4 fixed my issue after I made password reset for admin user

Answer (score 2):

When TFS Build reports the 503 error it can just be a temporary issue. This can happen if you are attempting to access the build server just after first configuring it—or, in your case, just after the TFS server has gone down and has been restarted—and the relevant services are not yet fully available.

Resolution in this case is simply a matter of waiting, and retrying in 5 or 10 minutes or so.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar result on TFS 2013 after rebooting the Server.  I received this message when accessing the TFS Administration Console->Change URL's->Test; or when trying to connect to TFS from Visual Studio 2010.  Another symptom is that if you have a Build Configuration setup, the Controller and Agent will not be available or visible in TFS Administration Console->Build Configuration.

The solution was to follow step #3 in the posting by Ivana b.  I didn't have a Process Model Section to update so I skipped #4.  Also, it was not a networking problem since I was able to connect to the Server using Remote Desktop and so #1 and #2 were not relevant to me either.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar problem on TFS 2015 Update 1 after rebooting. Some how Startup Type of Windows Process Activation Services were set to manual in Services. So I just set it to automatic then restarted the service and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For some inexplicable reason I had set the service account to me for TFS, and it stopped working when the password was changed.  Make sure in the TFS Admin Console under Application Tier you have the correct account set, and make sure that matches the accounts in IIS inside the Application Pool.  Sometimes when you're in a rush to get things up and started less than ideal things may occur.